# Correct date/time metadata for files on sharepoint based on file information from Word/Excel

Tags: metadata, sharepoint-online, directory-structure, office365api

Maybe someone has a good idea for the following problem.

In our company, we just went through a take-over of our Microsoft 365 domain. During that process, all data from the old sharepoint was downloaded to a NAS and later uploaded from the NAS to the new sharepoint.
Although this is basically good, all files within the folder structure of File Explorer (Windows) are now displayed with a wrong date and time of when they were created/edited.

When Office documents are opened with the corresponding app (Word, Excel, etc.) and are not changed/saved, the date and time of some additional (usually hidden) columns in File Explorer get updated with the relevant date/time.
Obviously, that doesn't apply to the last changed date and also it doesn't work for PDF documents.

[Columns before opening the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM10j.png)

[Columns after opening the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcsRt.png)

Therefore, my question is, whether it is somehow possible with a powershell script or with a tool to automatically correct the last changed date/time from the document information tags (metadata). Of course, the action itself must not be noticed as a change by sharepoint - otherwise it would not help us.

If I'd have to run a script/tool for each folder seperately, it would be ok, but it would be preferrable to be able to process all subfolders at once.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You might want to ask this on the SharePoint Stack Exchange: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: As I found out, the updated date/time gets undone, if the "Free up space" option from OneDrive is used.
@karttu: Thanks for the suggestion, I can do that.